# Signal conditioning for 2SMPP-03 Pressure sensor

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, analog, signal-processing, mems

I am wanting to develop a circuit that accurately measures 15 Omron 2SMPP-03 sensors within its full range of -50KPA to 50KPA. Could someone give me a head start or refer me to some information on how to design an applicaiton circuit that conditions + measures 15 of these reliably at the same time?

I understand the sensors needs to be driven by a constant current source but there is not much information or any examples online or in the datasheet.

http://components.omron.eu/Product-details/2SMPP-03

Thanks

Comment: what are the relevant paragraphs in the datasheet?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf What do you mean sorry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to an application note for this part...
https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en_a283_e1_01.pdf

Once you can work with one of them you can use a multiplexer of some sort to read as many of them as necessary.